# Iterate over an Excel workbook and index everything?

Tags: ruby, excel, csv, rubygems, iterator

This would be done in Ruby..I have provided what I have attempted thus far.

I am curious as to if it is possible to iterate over an excel workbook (so it would be multiple sheets) and basically index/record where everything is located.  Lets say I have a workbook of 10 sheets.  I want it to grab the first sheet, record that sheets name, then move to the first cell and begin indexing(not sure if correct word) the data on that sheet.  It would record the cell location so for the first (1,A) and the data thats in it.  I am trying to output the data into a format as such like a CSV file or something:[image]

Some code I have written that basically just iterates over every sheet and every cell in a workbook (removes whitespaces) and grabs its data and puts into a CSV...no sheet names or cell numbers present.  I am using the roo and csv gems:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

#Classes Used
class ArrayIterator
  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
    @index = 0
  end

  def has_next?
    @index < @array.length
  end

  def item
    @array[@index]
  end

  def next_item
    value = @array[@index]
    @index += 1
    value
  end
end

#Open up files to compare
w1 = Excelx.new ( "C:/Ruby/myworkbook.xlsx" )

$values = Array.new
i = 0.to_i
# Continue until no worksheets left
num_sheets = w1.sheets().size

while  (i < num_sheets)
      puts "i is currently : #{i}"
      puts "length of sheet array is : #{num_sheets}"

#Grab first sheet of each workbook
  w1.default_sheet = w1.sheets[i]
 1.upto(w1.last_row) do | row |
    1.upto(w1.last_column) do | column |
        string = w1.cell(row, column).to_s
        if (string.strip.empty?) 
          puts "Whitespace!"
                else
                  $values << string
        end
    end
 end
   i = i + 1.to_i
end  

count = 0.to_i
CSV.open('C:/Ruby/results.csv', "w") do |csv|   
 csv << ['String']
i = ArrayIterator.new($values)
   while i.has_next?
      csv << [i.next_item]
      count += 1
     end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty to shorten your script while adding check on empty sheets which produced errors.

```
require 'roo'

w1 = Excelx.new ( "C:/Ruby193/test/roo/book1.xlsx" )
CSV.open("book1.csv", "w") do |csv|   
  w1.sheets.each do |sheet|
    w1.default_sheet = sheet
    if w1.first_row && w1.first_column
      eval(w1.to_s).each do |index, value|
        csv << [sheet, index, value]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which gives in book1.csv

```
Sheet1,"[1, 1]",a1
Sheet1,"[1, 2]",b1
Sheet1,"[2, 1]",a2
Sheet1,"[2, 2]",b2
Sheet2,"[1, 1]",aa1
Sheet2,"[1, 2]",bb1
Sheet2,"[2, 1]",aa2
Sheet2,"[2, 2]",bb2
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I am new to Ruby so I havent fully grasped all the concepts.  It seems very elegant if you can condense what I wrote into this!